# Is it possible to run StyleCop on just 1 file in a project?

Tags: stylecop

Is it possible to run StyleCop on just 1 file in a project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, by selecting "Run StyleCop" from the context menu of the .cs file, not from the Tools menu or the project's context menu.

http://cleartopartlycloudy.blogspot.com/2009/06/stylecop-with-single-file.html

Comment: Or from the context menu of the text editor for the file i.e. if you've got the file open for edit in front of you then the context menu (or at least *my* context menu!) has "Run StyleCop" as the first menu item,