# Is It possible to run stylecop on a single file in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stylecop

I've tried looking for command line options etc. I'm trying to lower the time I have to wait to see if a build fails due to stylecop.

This option does not appear in any context menus or the tools menu: [Is it possible to run StyleCop on just 1 file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887776/is-it-possible-to-run-stylecop-on-just-1-file-in-a-project)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run StyleCop on just 1 file in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887776/is-it-possible-to-run-stylecop-on-just-1-file-in-a-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following context menus should contain commands for running StyleCop:

- At solution item in Solution Explorer (rescans the entire solution)
- At project item in Solution Explorer (rescans a project)
- At any single .cs file in Solution Explorer (scans single file)
- Inside text editor of any single .cs file (scans single file)

By the way, which StyleCop version do you use?
Have you considered any issues about wrong installation?

Comment: I'm not sure. I didn't install anything, I just have a Settings.StyleCop file that every project is using. I don't think I actually have "StyleCop" installed as part of visual studio.
StyleCopSettings Version="4.3" is in the file.

Comment: @shane When StyleCop is installed, there are 2 top-level options: "Visual Studio integration" and "MSBuild integration". I guess you have StyleCop installed with only the 2nd option enabled (which runs StyleCop as a part of your build process). So that seems you just don't have VS integration and you could download the MSI and "change" installation features.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves everything. The MSBuild stuff was integrated into our build by someone else, installing StyleCop on my own machine allowed me to get the VisualStudio stuff.